# Correct usage of WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, using, httpwebresponse

I need to use WebRequest to download a webpage content into a string.
I can't use WebClient instead because it doesn't support certain HTTP Headers which i need to use. I couldn't figure out what's the best practice for handling memory issues in this case (How to correctly dispose it). Is using a using statement enough or do i need to add some try catch stuff in here too?

This is my code so far:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.gooogle.com");

using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse()) {
  using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
    responseStream.ReadTimeout = 30;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
      var page = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine (except of course that some exception handling would be nice). You don't need to worry about disposing or closing streams when using `using`, the compiler generates the code for that.

The best thing would of course be to wrap the above code in a function that returns the page, and put a global try/catch in there, for instance:

```
public string GetHtmlPage(string urlToFetch)
{
    string page = "";

    try
    {
        ... code ...

        return page;
    } catch (Exception exc)
    {
        throw new HtmlPageRetrievalException(exc);
    }
}
```

Comment: This entire code block is inside a try/catch. Would that be enought or do i need to add some Exception handling within this block as well? Thanks...